# Expected value with uncertainty about parameters

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ which can take three values:
$P[X=1]=1-p\\P[X=0]=1/2\\P[X=-1]=p-1/2$

I know how to calculate the expected value when $p$ is a parameter, i.e. $E[X]=1-p-p+1/2=3/2-2p$. But what if $p$ is itself a random variable, say $P\sim U(0.5,1)$. Is the expectation then simply $E[X]=3/2-2E[p]=3/2-2*0.75=0$?

Comment: Yes. $E(X)=E(E(X|p))=E(3/2-2p)$ ($supp(p)\in[1/2,1]$)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to say is that if $p$ is a random variable, then
$X|p$ has a conditional distribution $P(X = 1) = 1-p,P(X = 0) = 1/2, P(X = -1) = p-1/2$.
Then
\begin{align*}
E[X] &= E\{E[X|p]\} \\
&= E\left[1(1-p)+0\cdot\frac{1}{2}+(-1)\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] \\
&= E\left[\frac{3}{2}-2p\right] \\
&=\frac{3}{2}-2E[p].
\end{align*}
To compute the final answer, you would need the distribution of $p$.
So if $p\sim\text{unif}(.5,1)$, then
$E[p] = \frac{3}{4}$, and
$$E[X] = \frac{3}{2}-2E[p] = \frac{3}{2}-2\frac{3}{4} = 0.$$